# Re-create a dynamic PHP URL with static HTML

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to recreate a URL structure of an archived site that used to run on PHP but is now HTML only.

Is it possible to recreate this URL: example.com/blogpost.php?id=23 with a pure HTML page?  I'm thinking mod_rewrite, but maybe there's something even easier?

Comment: Can you give an example of how the '.html' files are named and how they are structured in directories?

Comment: There are no limitations to that.  I am free to name them however and create additional directories.

Comment: If it's HTML only I would go with Node.js and use a catch-all like `example.com/:path` and send the corresponding file to the user.  To be clear, this is INSTEAD of apache/nginx/etc, not in addition to (although you can do both)

Comment: The concern is not sending files to users but Google complaining about 404s of what apparently are heavily linked pages externally.  Recreating the actual URLs in the browser is really the only task here.